# How to receive inputs from webform to my console application using Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, webforms

I have a console application that I wish to host on Microsoft Azure. I've designed a web form for users to submit two inputs necessary for the console application to run.

How can I get each input to the console application so that every time someone submits the web form, my console application runs in the background using those inputs and in return the console application sends them back the output in a .txt file or back to the web form directly?

Which Microsoft Azure services would I need to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Why not abstract the console app to a class library, then embed the library in both web form and console app separately?

Comment: I was thinking of converting the console application to .dll but I still don't know how to respond to the .dll directly from the web form. Thanks for mentioning that is is unsafe to trigger console application from a website. So I wouldn't need any other services from Azure if I did it with the .dll? @JasonW

Comment: Yes, you'll likely be seeing multiple security issues trying to run console app from Azure. You shouldn't need anything from Azure except ability to host .NET website/app. The dll would just contain your business logic for processing the inputs and returning the txt file (or some object) back to your code behind or MVC action in your website.  The DLL can also be shared in the same console app so your logic is shared between both deployments.

Comment: There are other asynchronous patterns if you run into issues with timeouts in case your processing takes to long for a standard web request. Many systems may use something like the Service Bus in Azure to enqueue a request, then a Worker role from Cloud Services to dequeue and process, and then the web app (in a Web Role from Cloud Services or just Website) to listen with a correlation id (async RPC enterprise messaging pattern) for response when request is processed (or just polling every few seconds waiting for async process to complete with the correlation id).

Comment: So once I convert my console application to a .dll, where would I have to put this .dll? And what additional coding has to be done to the text boxes on my web form or console application/dll?

Comment: You just add it as a reference in Visual Studio to your web form project. Then you can create objects from any of the classes from the library.

Comment: The web form was designed by someone else I can access the code to the web form only in Microsoft Azure. Should I just place the .dll in the directory where the web form is instead?

Comment: @JasonW would this be a problem for me since I'm not using visual studio to edit the web form?

Comment: @JasonW I think your way that you described is much easier to execute compared to FredHan's answer. Can you post a nice descriptive answer for your method so I can give you the credit for best answer? I have no experience when it comes to linking my web form with .dll so I'd appreciate it very much if you can go into detail as much as possible as to how I should do this. Thanks so much for your advice. You've already been a great help!

Comment: Just posted answer with details and how to add dll to "bin" directory so you don't directly need Visual Studio. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JasonW The web form that was designed for me has a .dll file in the bin folder. The .dll file doesnt really serve any purpose as it was just for testing. Will this be a problem for me as I am unable to edit .dll files. Or can I just overwrite his .dll with the proper web form .dll that we will have to make?

Comment: Depending on how the web form was built, I'd be careful if the existing DLL was required (maybe just back it up first in case there is a some existing dependency). You can add your own DLL in addition to the existing one. Larger apps may have dozens of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the details from the comments, one approach is to abstract the console app into a class library so the output DLL can be used in the Console and in your web forms application. It is usually a security risk to try to run console apps from a web application since it requires elevated permissions with the OS that is usually best left alone.

To utilize this DLL in the web forms, you normally would add the dll as a reference to your web forms project. As you mentioned since you're not directly using Visual Studio, you should be able to drop the DLL into the "bin" directory of the web forms application. Your code behind should work so long as you use proper namespaces/declarations.

Long term, if your logic is complicated and time-consuming to where you begin seeing timeouts waiting for the response, you may consider asynchronous messaging patterns such as RPC:

1. The web form code behind submits the request into an outbound queue (such as Service Bus in Azure) as a serialized request with only user inputs and a correlation id.
2. A separate web application (such as a cloud service in Azure in a worker role) would monitor the Service Bus, then post result on inbound queue with correlation id. If this response is a large file or content, you could consider creating the file (such as Azure Blob Storage or AWS S3, but persist only shortly) and only returning response with reference to the file instead of file.
3. The web form would poll periodically the inbound queue for the correlation id and respond with details for the user.

Comment: This is great!!! Thanks @JasonW, I just wanted to mention that yes the console application could take a very long time to finish processing. I also wanted to add that the users inputs will be large matrix arrays with many rows. (E.g. 1,2,3,4,5...) I just wanted to let you know in case there is a better within your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get each input to the console application so that every time someone submits the web form

If possible, you can contact webform project developer and let him [insert message to Azure queue storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#insert-a-message-into-a-queue) in webform submit event and set message body with user’s inputs value.

And you can make/modify your console application as [QueueTrigger WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to#trigger) that will be triggered when a queue message is received.

Comment: if I do this, should I keep the console application as a .exe or should I still convert to .dll for security reasons?

Comment: Also, what is the best queue storage method for sending/receiving matrix arrays? (E.g. 1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: I did some research and it looks like there is a cap on how big a message can be using the insert message to Azure queue storage. Is this correct?

Comment: [Maximum message size of storage queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#capacity-and-quotas) is 64 KB (48 KB when using Base64 encoding).

Comment: 64kb is way too tiny for my sake.

Comment: Azure supports large messages by combining queues and blobs , you can store your payload in blob and the maintain the URI pointing to the blob in your queue message.

Comment: Is there a size limit for blobs?

Comment: Max size of a block blob is 50,000 X 100 MB (approx. 4.75 TB), you can get detailed information from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets#scalability-targets-for-blobs-queues-tables-and-files).